# {}.toString() vs ({}.toString())

Tags: javascript

Why below code is working:

```
({}.toString()) // "[object Object]"
```

but this not:

```
{}.toString() //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: `{}` in the beginning of the line is interpreted as an empty code block. Then you have `.toString()` which is just not valid code.